# Correct way of locking a mutex in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to implement a simple thread-safe Buffer, using Kotlin Coroutines, because coroutines are already used within the project.

The buffer will be used both in multi-thread and single-thread contexts, so having `suspend fun getMostRecentData()` doesn't seem very reasonable (see code below).

This is what I have so far. The fact that I have to write all that code to lock the mutex makes me wonder if I'm doing something wrong.

Anyway here's the code:

```
class SafeBuffer(
    private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
    private val bufferSize: Int
    ) {

    private val buffer = LinkedList<MyDataType>()
    private val mutex = Mutex()

    val size: Int
        get() = buffer.size

   // First approach: make a suspend fun
   // Not great because I will need a runBlocking{} statement somewhere, every time I want to access the buffer
   suspend fun getMostRecentData() : MyDataType? {
        mutex.withLock {
            return if (buffer.isEmpty()) null else buffer.last
        }
    }

   // Second approach: use a runBlocking block inside the function
   // Seems like it is missing the purpose of coroutines, and I'm not 
   // sure it is actually thread safe if other context is used somehow?
   fun getMostRecentData() : MyDataType? {
        runBlocking(dispatcher) {
            mutex.withLock {
                return if (buffer.isEmpty()) null else buffer.last
            }
        }
    }

    /**** More code ****/
    (...)

}
```

So what's the most idiomatic/elegant way of achieving this?

Comment: "I will need a runBlocking{} statement somewhere, every time I want to access the buffer" why do you _need_ this? The only requirement for calling a `suspend fun` is to call it within another coroutine.

Comment: the only thing `runBlocking` achieves is blocking the entire thread until the `suspend fun` launched inside of it completes. It doesn't impact the usage of the `mutex`, so perhaps you have some other confusion here

Comment: @WilliamReed for locking the mutex you need to be within a `suspend` function or a coroutine, hence the `runBlocking` statement.
If I am running on a single threaded environment (which my class shall also support), I will need to create a coroutine or use a `runBlocking`statement if my understanding is correct, which makes no sense in a single threaded env.

Comment: i don't think you want to use `runBlocking` by default. Let the users of this class determine if they want that or not. The idomatic approach would be to only expose your first `suspend fun`. If you want a blocking alternative, consider creating an extension function to also offer that. Extension functions are used like crazy in the coroutines API

Comment: Thanks @WilliamReed. Would you consider adding an example and I would accept as reply?

Comment: Are you sure you actually need a lock to make the buffer concurrent? There are plenty concurrent, lock-free queues out there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, I think it would be idiomatic to have the buffer class only expose a `suspend fun`, as the consumer of the class would be responsible for figuring out how they want to use it (via `runBlocking` or from another coroutine). If you see this use case coming up a lot, an idiomatic approach may be to have an extension function on `SafeBuffer` to offer this functionality.

Extension functions are used all over the place in the coroutines API. In your code example, even `Mutex.withLock` is defined as an extension function.

```kotlin
class SafeBuffer(...) {

    private val buffer = LinkedList<MyDataType>()
    private val mutex = Mutex()

    suspend fun getMostRecentData() : MyDataType? =
        mutex.withLock {
            if (buffer.isEmpty()) null else buffer.last
        }
}

fun SafeBuffer.getMostRecentDataBlocking(): MyDataType? =
    runBlocking {
        getMostRecentData()
    }
```

Comment: And just to add a note, no one is going to care very much if you added `getMostRecentDataBlocking` directly to the `SafeBuffer` class. I'm just speaking from my POV of reading through coroutine source code and how I have seen a lot of their code defined.